# Event datetime is being stored incorrectly in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, datetime, facebook-php-sdk

Event 'start_time' is being stored incorrectly into mysql database.

events that store incorrectly

https://graph.facebook.com/112797205532177 - stores as 2012-10-12 19:00:00
correct is 2012-10-13

```
{
"id": "112797205532177", 
"owner": {
    "name": "MUST...NOT...KILL", 
    "category": "Musician/band", 
    "id": "108837005801452"
}, 
"name": "METAL MEOWLISHA", 
"description": "W/ Brutailty", 
"start_time": "2012-10-13", 
"location": "The brass mug", 
"venue": {
    "id": "151496721577181"
}, 
"privacy": "OPEN", 
"updated_time": "2012-07-27T21:20:20+0000"
}
```

https://graph.facebook.com/278345158937377 - stored as 2012-11-18 18:00:00
correct is 2012-11-19

```
{
"id": "280381075399709", 
"owner": {
    "name": "Lamb of God", 
    "category": "Musician/band", 
    "id": "9008741434"
}, 
  "name": "Lamb of God On Tour", 
  "description": "Wed/Oct-31\tLos Angeles, CA @ TBA\t", 
  "start_time": "2012-10-31", 
  "privacy": "OPEN", 
  "updated_time": "2012-09-05T21:37:29+0000"
}
```

i have been searching the net checking for the solution. with no luck

the goal is to store the exact field 'start_time' with no conversion. there is no conversion in my code. i am thinking it has to do with php settings

**Edit: added the returned results from the graph api and here is my insert string(in codeigniter**

```
$eventdata = array(
            'artists_name'=>$artists,
            'event_status'=>$event_stat,
            'formatted_datetime'=>$formatted_datetime,
            'formatted_location'=>$formatted_location,
            'event_id'=>$event_id,
            'venue_name'=>$venue_name,
            'venue_city'=>$vcity,
            'venue_region'=>$vstate,
            'venue_country'=>$vcountry,
            'venue_lat'=>$vlat,
            'venue_long'=>$vlong,
            'date_time'=>$date_time,
            'rsvp_url'=>$rsvp_url,
            'ticket_url'=>$ticket_url,
            'updated'=>$updated);
            $eventinsert = $this->db->insert_string('newEvents',$eventdata);
            $this->db->query($eventinsert);
```

thanks

**EDIT this is the complete php file**

```
include 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
));


$check = $facebook->api('278345158937377');
print_r ($check['start_time']);

?>
```

Stripped everything out i could so far. i find it odd that a string result would get autoconverted before displaying.

graph and fql on facebooks site display 2012-11-19
my site displays 2012-11-18

Comment: I have no idea from where you're getting `start_time` from and how you're inserting it into the database...

Comment: How do you retrieve the date? How do you store it in PHP? How do you store it in MySQL?

Comment: Can you post the contents of what the facebook graph API is reeturning? We can't see the data being returned without your accesskey. We also can't see the actual MySQL `INSERT` command you're executing. From your limited description, it sounds like you're hitting a Time Zone issue.

Comment: retrieve date from via facebooks php sdk and store in mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the GMT offset to the time and THEN store it.

Example: Im in EST, the time difference is 5 hours, so add 18000 to the unix time stamp

Answer (score 0):

Does your app have the [Events Timezone](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/01/platform-migration--events-timezone-support/) migration enabled?

When I query event 278345158937377 with an access token generated by an app without the migration enabled, Facebook returns `"start_time": "2012-11-19T01:00:00"`.

When I make it from an app with the timezone migration enabled, the API call returns `"start_time": "2012-11-19"`.

Try enabling this migration from the advanced tab of your app dashboard and see if that eliminates your problem.

Comment: i enabled that setting in the app dashboard. ran the script once.. some seem to be correct. facebook did say that it could take several minutes to propagate all the servers.

Comment: when i check from the graph api tool. they are all correct. they just don't store correctly in mysql

Comment: The Graph API tool has the migration enabled for "Graph API Explorer" access tokens. Change to your app access token using the "Application" drop down at the upper right and see if you get the same result.

Comment: You shouldn't trust the Graph API's results either for your script. `print_r()` your result and make sure it matches what you expect.

Comment: check graph api results with my app selected.  same results.. now ill check the print_r results

Comment: Checked the data(batch call). all the same. even did a single query to check. it was the same also

Comment: I'm stumped. You might want to check your server's time zone settings.

Comment: i have completely dumbed down what i was doing to check if i was doing something wrong.